# React / Material UI: Styling / customizing components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working with Material UI as part of React. I'm a little confused as to the most useful way to style and customize components.

What I have found so far for options:

**A: Global via custom theme**

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#000",
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiBottomNavigation: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "#000",
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

What bothers me is that I can't reuse previously defined variables. For example, I have to redefine the primary color every time I want to assign this color to a component.

**B: Using the style API (makeStyle)**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    BottomNavigation: {
        height: 60,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark
    }
})

function Menu() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    // and so on
}
```

Here I am bothered by the fact that I can only create classes for the direct component. Here it is not possible for me to style other classes like e.g. the label of the component (BottomNavigationAction).

**C: Via CSS classes**

```
<BottomNavigationAction classes={{ label: 'my-class-name' }} label="Dashboard" icon={<WbSunnyOutlinedIcon />} />
```

This way I could easily style each component via CSS. But don't I leverage the principle of Material UI?

**Are there more possibilities? What is the best way to style or customize a component?**

Answer (score 0):

While I personally prefer to use the makeStyle option, I know that MUI recommends their ['system' solution](https://mui.com/system/basics/#why-use-the-system) for styling